# flag change based on occurrence

Tags: sql

I have below table as input

```
id|type
1|manager
1|non manager
1|manager
1|non manager
1|non manager
1|manager
```

desired output:
if more than one id falling into manager and non manager hen it should show as mixed as shown below.

```
id|type
1|mixed
```

Can anyone help ..

Comment: The sample data could have an id 2 with only one kind of type. To make the problem clearer.

Answer (score 2):

One method uses window functions:

```
select id,
       (case when max(type) over (partition by id) =
                  min(type) over (partition by id)
             then max(type) over (partition by id)
             else 'Mixed'
        end) as type
from t;
```

Or, `exists` comes to mind as well:

```
select id,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from t t2
                          where t2.id = t.id and t2.type <> t.type
                         )
             then 'Mixed' else type
        end) as type
from t;
```

EDIT:

To get one row per id, just use aggregation:

```
select id,
       (case when max(type) = min(type)
             then max(type)
             else 'Mixed'
        end) as type
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: change in the output requirement ,, can you help me plz